# DrawableAnimation cause the layout flicking

Tags: android, animationdrawable

I have an view which has an DrawableAnimation background in the layout, I get the animation drawable and start animation or stop animation like below code

```
private void init() {
    xxx.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.avatar_wave_profile);
    mAnimationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable)mAvatarWave.getBackground();
} 

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    if (hasFocus) {
        mAnimationDrawable.start();
    } else {
        mAnimationDrawable.stop();
    }
}
```

But when i touch the layout or the layout is moving(in an sliding menu), it will flicker.
so how to avoid this problem, any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

remove that animation controlling functionality in onWindowFocusChange() and place in init() method, Becose onWindowFocusChange() calls when window focus is changed this method will call.

plz check this reference.[Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onWindowFocusChanged%28boolean%29)

Comment: The animation can't start if put the code in `onCreate`, as well i just followed the the developer guide : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html